# TinkerGraph retrieval inconsistency when using ids as String vs Long

Tags: gremlin

When I store a vertex in TinkerGrapg I see that the ids are long:

```
{TinkerVertex@7955} "v[304]"
```

when I do:

```
graph.V(304).next();
```

it doesn't work!

when I do:

```
graph.V("304").next();
```

it doesn't work!

when I do:

```
graph.V(304l).next();
```

or

```
graph.V(new Long(304)).next();
```

it works!

I am trying to use the same Gremlin code both against TinkerGraph and DSE Graph..The problem is that one returns `long` and the other one as strings

I am curious how I could make the same Gremlin work with int/long and String ids at the same time.. is this a problem of the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinkerGraph uses and `IdManager` which can coerce identifiers to different types. You can read more about that [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration_2) but basically if you want to have `g.V(1)` and `g.V(1L)` both return a value you'd want to configure your TinkerGraph as follows:

```
gremlin> conf = new BaseConfiguration()
==>org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration@552518c3
gremlin> conf.setProperty('gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager',"LONG")
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open(conf)
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV(id, 1L)
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.addV(id, 2)
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V(1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V(1L)
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V(2L)
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V(2)
==>v[2]
```

In fact, even this works when you use an `IdManager`:

```
gremlin> g.V("2")
==>v[2]
```

You can specify your own `IdManager` implementation to TinkerGraph if you like - just supply the fully qualified classname to the configuration (i.e. instead of "LONG").